# The "try_files" directive in nginx does not work correctly for PHP files

Tags: php, nginx

I have a fully static website restored from web.archive.org. I am trying to achieve the following result in nginx using the try_files directive. Files of the form xxx?q=1 should be opened exactly as they are stored in the file system. Everything works as expected, except for files with the .phph extension (e.g., aaa.php?q=1). In this case, all requests result in the file aaa.php being loaded.

I am using the following code for the virtual host:

```
server {
    server_name xxx.kz;
    root /mnt/data/web/www;
    error_log /mnt/data/web//logs/error.log error;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $request_uri $request_uri/index.html =404;
        error_page 404 http://$host/;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        types { } default_type text/html;
    }
}
```

Please advise on where the error may be.

Comment: The URI `aaa.php?q=1` is not processed by the `try_files` because its handled by a different `location` block. You need to place another `try_files` statement in the other `location` block if that `location` block is needed.

Comment: You mean I need to duplicate it in my second block for php files?

Comment: Yes. The URI `aaa.php?q=1` matches the `location ~* \.php$` block. So to make your `try_files` rule take effect, it needs to be present in that block also.